# Power source switching circuit with load as a voltage source

Tags: power-supply, voltage-source

I want to design a power source switcher for Raspberry Pi Zero. Computer has to be powered from Li-Ion battery when no USB is connected and disconnect the bettery immediately when USB voltage is present.
Most of circuits I found require placing a diode between voltage source and a load - since one of the voltage sources is "inside" the computer I can't do that.

Crude representation of this circuit would be: (computer accepts both voltages)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fALPeU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm pretty sure diode is not a right component to use here.

*My question is: Can I use reverse current blocking circuit using two FET transistors in this application? Like this one:*
[image]

I made a circuit that works in simulation, will it work in practice?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxV6ZR.png)</sup>

Comment: The power source doesn't have to be inside the computer. You can add a USB port to your circuit.

Comment: Yes, I know that :) but on the USB there are also data lines which I want to preserve. (And can't connect to them)

Comment: You are focusing on only one part of a problem that is much more complex than you realize.  If you absolutely must do this, start by reviewing the designs *and user experiences* of various add-ons sold as backup power supplies for pis.

Comment: @Poij I don't own a Pi Zero, but a google search tells me that it has *two* USB ports - one with data lines, and one for power

Comment: @user253751 more usefully it has the 5v rails on the 40-pin GPIO connector; however, they'd be connected through to the data port too.  So modification (or a cable with a cut lead) would be needed.  And then it's technically out of USB spec.  And anyway, there is far more to the problem being addressed - power a pi directly off a single LiPo doesn't look great, likely the power-quality logic will asses a firm "nope"!

Comment: Someone made a project with Pi Zero powered from Li-Ion: https://hackaday.io/project/19035-zerophone-a-raspberry-pi-smartphone/log/69596-a-guide-on-powering-pi-zero-directly-from-liion-batteries
It was my inspiration for this concept, it's all OK but I would really want to use Pi's USB while battery is connected.

Comment: Regarding the add-ons - they mostly work by stepping-up battery voltage and that's something I want to aviod. Also, so far this is only a concept project, I do not have to do this if it wouldn't work.

Comment: I also made a progress by simulating circuit that works as I want it to. I would update the question in a moment...

Comment: @user253751 Yes, Pi has two power ports but the "data" one can still power the board and that's my main issue.